# Using BeautifulSoup to extract page information within div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the number of pages (in this case 156) from the div class. The code is shown below.

```
   <div class="listing-count-label listing-count-holder listing-count-holder-header">8007 listings, showing 1 to 156</div>
```

I currently have :

```
page = soup.find("div",{"class":"listing-count-label listing-count-holder listing-count-holder-header"})
for x in page:
    print (x.text)
```

yields:

> [ ]

ultimately i want page = 156.

Comment: `x.text.split(' ')[-1]` would give you page no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, the `find()` returns a *single element* (a [`Tag`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) instance) which can also be *iterable* - you would iterate over the element's children. And, since there is only a single child - a text node, the @Dekel's answer would work.

But, you don't really need the `for` loop and can simple get the text directly:

```
page = soup.find("div", {"class":"listing-count-label listing-count-holder listing-count-holder-header"})
print(page.get_text())
```

Also, you don't really need to list all the classes of an element to locate it, you can use a single one:

```
soup.find("div", class_="listing-count-label")
```

Or, with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select_one("div.listing-count-label")
```

---

But, since you are up to the page count, why don't we locate the element by the text using a [regular expression](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) - and, we'll use the same regular expression to extract the page count number:

```
>>> import re
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """<div class="listing-count-label listing-count-holder listing-count-holder-header">8007 listings, showing 1 to 156</div>"""
>>> 
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"\d+ listings, showing \d+ to (\d+)")
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
>>> 
>>> pattern.search(soup.find(text=pattern)).group(1)
u'156'
```

And, you can convert it to an integer using `int()`. But, this code missing error-handling - things can go wrong - make sure to handle errors appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `x` in your example is [`NavigableString` object](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring), which doesn't have the a `text` attribute. The only thing you need to do is use this `x` or convert it to `string` (using `str(x)`):

```
>>> page = soup.find("div",{"class":"listing-count-label listing-count-holder listing-count-holder-header"})
>>> for x in page:
...    print (x)
8007 listings, showing 1 to 156
```

Answer (score 1):

The `find` method will find one tag object. Instead of using `for` syntax, just write `page.text`.

Answer (score 1):

```
number = soup.find('div', class_='listing-count-label').text.split()[-1]

text: 8007 listings, showing 1 to 156
split_text :['8007', 'listings,', 'showing', '1', 'to', '156']
```

First, `find()` will return **a** tag, so you cannot iterate over it, the number is in the tag's text, so you can use `.text` to get the text and split it by space, and get the last element of the split list.

Second, you can use part of class attribute to filter tags, no need to use whole attrbute.

> Remember that a single tag can have multiple values for its “class”
>   attribute. When you search for a tag that matches a certain CSS class,
>   you’re matching against any of its CSS classes:
>
> ```
> css_soup = BeautifulSoup('<p class="body strikeout"></p>')
> css_soup.find_all("p", class_="strikeout")
> # [<p class="body strikeout"></p>]
>
> css_soup.find_all("p", class_="body")
> # [<p class="body strikeout"></p>]
> ```